# How to parse the CSV data in HTML page in Django Server?

Tags: python, html, django

**I have used the following function in views.py**

```
 def getdata(request):
    with open('./studata.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
        csv_file_reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        records = list(csv_file_reader)
        count = len(records)
    return render(request,'showdata.html',{'records':records})
```

**Here is the csv file -**

```
Roll,Name,Stream
11,Bedanta Borah,Non-Medical,
1,Varsha Sharma,Non-Medical,
3,Nancy,Commerce,
4,Akshita,Humanities,
```

> This data should be displayed in showdata.html. How do I traverse through the data in the HTML page ?

Comment: Note you're not "parsing CSV data in the HTML page", you're already parsed the CSV by creating your `records` object. `records` is a python object. To be precise, it's a **list** of **dictionaries**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```
<div>
    {% for record in records %}
       {{ record.Roll }}
       {{ record.Name}}
       {{ record.Stream}}
</div>
```

See this for more info [info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for)